# Is there a way of doing something like #![allow(unstable)] on the command line?

Tags: rust

By command line, I mean by using a `rustc` flag.

It would be a convenient option, compared to adding `#![allow(unstable)]` lines in those source files... I am building a whole bunch at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rustc -A unstable foo.rs
```

Running `rustc --help` has this snippet of arguments:

```
-W --warn OPT       Set lint warnings
-A --allow OPT      Set lint allowed
-D --deny OPT       Set lint denied
-F --forbid OPT     Set lint forbidden
```

You can get the current list of lints with `rustc -W help`